# Log Writer not creating new line for each entry

Tags: vb.net, file, streamwriter

I get the feeling this is something really simple, but I've tried I don't know how many permutations of `vbNewLine`, `Environment.NewLine`, `sMessage & vbNewLine (or Environment.Newline)` I've tried, or how many pages on this site, or through Google I've looked at but nothing has worked.

I even tried getting help from a VB.Net discord channel I'm a part of and they suggested to do the same things that I've done and the procedure is still writing each new log entry at the end of the previous one in a continuous string. My writer is below. Am I missing something simple?

Edit:  The code that worked is below in case anyone else comes along with the same issue. If you want to see the original code it's in the edit log.

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System.IO

Public Class WriteroLog
    Public Shared Sub LogPrint(sMessage As String)
        Dim AppPath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath

        If File.Exists($"{AppPath}\Log.txt") = True Then
            Try
                Using objWriter As StreamWriter = File.AppendText($"{AppPath}\Log.Txt")
                    objWriter.WriteLine($"{Format(Now, "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")} – {sMessage}")
                    objWriter.Close()
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex)
                Return
            End Try
        Else
            Try
                Using objWriter As StreamWriter = File.CreateText($"{AppPath}\Log.Txt")
                    objWriter.WriteLine($"{Format(Now, "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")} – {sMessage}")
                    objWriter.Close()
                End Using

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex)
                Return
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: WriteLine doesn't require any added newline to its output. How do you look at the resulting file? What application are you using to read it?

Comment: It's a .txt file and I'm using notepad to view it and you're right, none of the newline statements should be necessary, but without them, it still just appends to the end of the string in the file rather than creating a new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [File.AppendText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=netframework-4.7.2) method creates a new [StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netframework-4.7.2) that is then used to append Text to the specified File.
Note, reading the Docs about this method, that you don't need to verify whether the File already exists: if it doesn't, the File is automatically created.

As a side note, when creating a Path, it's a good thing to use the [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.IO.Path.Combine);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) method: it can prevent errors in the path definition and handles platform-specific formats.

Your code could be simplified as follows:

```
Public Shared Sub LogPrint(sMessage As String)
    Dim filePath As String = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Log.Txt")

    Try
        Using writer As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(filePath)
            writer.WriteLine($"{Date.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")} – {sMessage}")
        End Using
    Catch ex As IOException
        MsgBox(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The File.CreateText does not assign result to "objWrite", should be:

```
objWriter = File.CreateText($"{AppPath}\Log.Txt")
```

Not really sure if this is the root of your problem, but it is an issue.

Comment: it's not because the log file does exist in the project's directory so the logic check is true, but good catch. I'm going to fix that before I forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

In essences, your logic is re-opening or creating the stream "objWriter" for every call to this method.  I would recommend you initialize "objWriter" to Nothing and only define if it is Nothing.

Set to Nothing as below.

```
Shared objWriter As IO.StreamWriter = Nothing
```

Then add check for Nothing in logic.